# building NuGet package; want to add content to disk, but not solution

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am building a NuGet package.  I want to add content that will be written to disk, but not added to the project.  I've looked at many websites and the available documentation, but nothing is jumping out at me.

I suspect I could achieve this in a round about scripting way, but would prefer a simpler solution.

Comment: "add content that will be written to disk, but not added to the project"

Could you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: When I add content in a package, the solution is automatically adding it.  I have to go in and ignore.  Use case, is that I want to make my CMS system a Nuget package, but there is no need to reference all of that bloat

Comment: that said, this might not be a Nuget spec problem, but a vs setting problem.  I have a workaround, but just wondering.

Comment: Rob, it certainly sounds more like a VS solution settings issue than a NuGet-specific one. You should not be adding NuGet packages to a VS solution.